# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a url, which i can hit with postman as well as directly on browser. But with python, i always get this error.Also tried with verify=False.

Please check and suggest.

Additional info:
OS: MAC
Python: 2.7

```
>>> requests.get(url)                                                                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 314, in _raise_timeout
    if 'timed out' in str(err) or 'did not complete (read)' in str(err):  # Python 2.6
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)
```

Comment: What is the value of `url`?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/556